# Having problems with a java program

Tags: java

I have a **Fahrenheit** class thats supposed to take a number from the main class and convert it into celsius. 
Everything works but the conversion part. 
I made a method that I call so that the number can be converted, but whenever the program runs it gives me either -0.0 or 0.0 (no matter what the number is) I know that the negative part is correct but i just need it to show the actual converted number.

It has been an entire year since I've done any sort of java programming and I'm still a beginner.I've looked up the java docs to get a refresher and wrote simple simple programs to get back in the game but im lost with this one. please any input would be helpful

heres the main class

```
public class test { 
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    double t = 100;

    Fahrenheit temp = new Fahrenheit(t);

    temp.convert();

  }
}
```

and the fahrenheit class

```
public class Fahrenheit{

 private double tempF = 0;

 public Fahrenheit (double inputTemp){
    tempF = inputTemp;
 }

public double convert () {

    double c = 5/9*(tempF-32);

    System.out.println(c );
    return c;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
double c = 5/9*(tempF-32);
```

In the above line, you are performing integer division - `5 / 9`, whose result is `0`. Hence you got `0.0`.

You can either change one of the `numerator` or `denominator` to a `double value`: -

```
double c = 5.0 / 9 * (tempF-32);
```

or, just do the multiplication first: -

```
double c = 5 * (tempF-32) / 9 ;
```

Comment: LOL man this always happens... always the simplest thing haha thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 double c = 5/9*(tempF-32);
```

In the above line, you are performing integer division  5 / 9, whose result is 0.

You can also use:

```
double c = (double)5/9*(tempF-32);
```

or

```
double c = 5.0 / 9 * (tempF-32);
```